# Which word describes this concept?

Tags: single-word-requests

Someone is having a bad (or good) day, and from the events that happened to him/her, this person thinks that the universe is against (or very good with) him/her. Then, an event happens that is so good (or bad) that it seems to make this day suddenly seem to become the opposite of what it was. It could be anything like winning the lottery, his/her crush deciding to date him/her, this same crush rejecting him/her when it seemed that such a thing wouldn't ever happen, or a relative dying. What word defines this event that seems contrary to how the day initially seemed to be? I'd like the word to be an adjective but if it can't be an adjective then I guess I'll need to accept another type of word besides adjectives. The word needs to be used to say things like "What a(n) [...] event" or "This event really is/would be [...]". Thank you in advance.

Comment: What should the adjective be modifying? “What word is defined as this event...” makes it seem like a job for a noun.

Comment: I hope it'll now make better sense that I edited that part to clarify it. The word needs to be used to say things like "What a(n) <word> event" or "This event really is <word>".

Comment: You should add your sample sentences to the question since comments can be removed.

Comment: It's the [*vagaries*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/vagaries) — the unpredictable ups and downs — of life.

Comment: From the SWR tag: "This tag is for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning. To ensure that your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word.  INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used."

Answer (score 2):

**vicissitudes** neatly sums it up.

> a favorable or unfavorable event or situation that occurs by chance : a fluctuation of state or condition

*the vicissitudes of daily life*

[Merriam-Webster]

Comment: This word is quite close to what I want to say though it'd be better if the word's definition stated that the event or situation the word describes is so favorable (or unfavorable) that it changes a particular time period from good/bad to bad/good. If such a word doesn't exist then you can also say that the word I'm looking for doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

A day with so many reversals of fortune might be called **a day worthy of the Fates.**

Wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fates

The concept that you want to convey is very complicated. This means that the adjective or phrase you want will almost certainly have to be drawn from literature or mythological concepts that are widely known.

You can make up an adjective related to a character in a more contemporary work, but here you have to know your audience. Even the most widely-watched TV shows have not been seen by everyone. Nor have most video games.

Answer (score 0):

How about reversal?

From https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reversal

> > 3: a change (as of fortune) often for the worse

Comment: The word looks good but seems like it needs more words after it or before it in order to convey the meaning I want (except if it can convey it alone, I don't know that, if it does you can tell me).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [game changer](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/game%20changer)

> a newly introduced element or factor that changes an existing situation or activity in a significant way.

This can be used to describe the event that changed how the day unfolded.

> I woke up feeling miserable, but winning the lottery was a real *game changer*.